# SQL - just view the description for explanation

Tags: sql, string

I would like to ask if it is possible to do this:

For example the search string is '009' -> (consider the digits as string)

is it possible to have a query that will return any occurrences of this on the database not considering the order.

for this example it will return

'009'
'090'
'900'

given these exists on the database. thanks!!!!

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Like` operator.

**For Example :-**

```
SELECT Marks FROM Report WHERE Marks LIKE '%009%' OR '%090%' OR '%900%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into individual characters, select all rows containing the first character and put them in a temporary table, then select all rows from the temporary table that contain the second character and put these in a temporary table, then select all rows from *that* temporary table that contain the third character.

Of course, there are probably many ways to optimize this, but I see no reason why it would not be *possible* to make a query like that work.

Answer (score 0):

It can not be achieved  in a straight forward way as there is no `sort()` function for a particular value like there is `lower()`, `upper()` functions.

---

But there is some workarounds like -

Suppose you are running query for `COL A`, maintain another column `SORTED_A` where from application level you keep the sorted value of `COL A`

Then when you execute query - sort the `searchToken` and run select query with matching `sorted searchToken` with the `SORTED_A` column